# Пользователь с клавиатуры вводит числа,если встречается отрицательное число,предыдущие складываются,если отрицательное отсутствует,программа кончается

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++

Добрый день уважаемые товарищи,написал программу,при запуске работает,однако не работают условия(точнее работают,но не правильно),получается полная каша,подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать правильно? само задание в названии

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int mas[5], x, y, i,l,sum;
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
        printf("Введите элемент массива:\n");
        cin >> mas[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if (mas[i] < 0)
        {
            for (l = 0; l < i; l++)
            {
                sum = +mas[l];
                printf("сумма равна\n");
                cout << sum;
            }
        }
        else printf("все числа положительны\n");

    }

}
```

Comment: каша подразумевается постоянный вывод "все числа положительны"
и в принципе результат программы выходит не верный.
прошу мне ОБЪЯСНИТЬ,пожалуйста,хочу понять в чём дело

Comment: `sum = +mas[l];` не смущает

Comment: @user7860670 а разве есть альтернатива найти сумму чисел массива?

Comment: а в этом выражении никакого суммирования не происходит...

Comment: я заменил
sum = +mas[l]; 
на
sum = sum+mas[l];
однако лучше не стало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если правильно понял задачу

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
  int mas[5], x, y, i, l, sum;
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
  sum = 0;
  bool good = true;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("Введите элемент массива:%d\n", i + 1);
    cin >> mas[i];
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (mas[i] < 0) {
      for (l = 0; l < i; l++) {
        sum += mas[l];
      }
      printf("сумма равна\n");
      cout << sum;
      sum = 0;
      good = false;
    }

  }
  if (good) {
    printf("все положительные");

  }
}
```

Comment: Да,абсолютно верно,спасибо большое,буду разбирать

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста смысл данной строки
 if (good) {
    printf("все положительные"); 
я понимаю что это условие,а good-логический тип,но как это получается?
(я только осваиваю С++ и стараюсь вникать во всё)

Comment: У нас есть переменная которая хранит в себе то, все ли числа положительные, если встречается отрицательное она хранит ложь, в той строке при проверке на истину выводится сообщение

Comment: Спасибо большое за объяснение